# what are the differences between these nasm stack pushes?

Tags: assembly, stack, nasm, 16-bit

this is in 16 bit, real mode, NASM.

```
 ; ---- variables ------
    cursorRow db 1
 .
 .
 .

 ; what are the differences between these two pushes?
 push cursorRow ; is this the address of?

 push [cursorRow] ; is this the value of?
```

I'm having trouble altering this variable in function where cursorRow is a parameter. 
A question I posted that is relevant: [Updating variable that lives in the data segment from the stack and its segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659234/updating-variable-that-lives-in-the-data-segment-from-the-stack-and-its-segment)

Comment: I think both of those will push the *value* of cursorRow depending on your assembler (you can always disassemble the file to know for sure). `mov ax, offset cursorRow; push ax` should push the address at least. `lds si, [cursorRow]; push ds; push si` should push a far pointer, but it's been a while since I did multi-segment 16-bit programs.

Comment: I'm using NASM and it doesn't have the offset keyword as far as I know. last night I got my program to work by pushing the address of cursorRow with the following instruction: `push cursorRow`

Comment: Did you read nasmdoc? I remember there was a section specifically describing this part as being different from other assemblers such as MASM and TASM.

Answer (score 1):

cursorRow is the value and [cursorRow] is the value at location cursorRow. If you need to put the address of cursorRow on the stack then you need to push bp+1 or whatever the actual address of the variable is

Answer (score 1):

If cursorRow (not [cursorRow] ) is initiated in the data section, it is like a C pointer.  Using [cursorRow] would dereference it and return the value stored there and you'll have to prefix [cursorRow] with the size of value like `mov al, byte [cursorRow]`.